# Removing Top Heading

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have a default heading where there is the application name and a drop down menu of setting.

I am new to android so i was google on how to remove it, but i was unlucky to find a proper solution.

So how can i remove the top application name(AndroidAppOnTheWay) with drop down setting tab.

I tried removing some xml lines from mainactivity.xml file but whenever i build and run my program it crashes and gives an error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `Theme` that doesn't contain `ActionBar`

For example:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make the title tag in your manifest.xml empty. This worked for me every time i need it. I don't know if this is best practise.